# How to convert LiveData Entitiy to LiveData Domain model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, dao

I'm developing MVVM kotlin application with repository pattern

I have separated my model classes as below

- classes represents the data coming from network
- classes represents entities for the room database
- classes that represents the domain

In my repository I want always to return the domain object not the network object or the entity object.

In my Dao I insert and retrieve entity object as below

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertAsteroids(asteroid: List<AsteroidEntity>)

@Query("SELECT * FROM asteroid_tbl")
fun getAsteroidsFromDb () : LiveData<List<AsteroidEntity>>
```

And I have a function in the repository that returns the list of asteroids as Live data from room as below

```
override suspend fun getAsteroids(): LiveData<List<Asteroid>> {
            return appLocalDb.asteroidDao.getAsteroidsFromDb()
}
```

But the issue is the dao returns a `LiveData<List<AsteroidEntity>>`
while the repository I want it to return the domain model as
`LiveData<List<Asteroid>>`

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should use the approach of [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572879/3290339) a DAO to a model object.

Comment: I do have a mapper that maps entity to domain model. But in my case I have a live data of list of domain object.The mapper is simply convert an entity object to domain object or list of entity object to list of domain object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Transformations.map`

```
override suspend fun getAsteroids(): LiveData<List<Asteroid>> {
            return Transformations.map(appLocalDb.asteroidDao.getAsteroidsFromDb()) { it.map{ item -> Asteroid(item.name,....)} }
}
```

For Further Documentation checkout the docs
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations

Comment: the "it" here represents a list of asteroid and not a single object. I need to iterate over the list

Comment: This will cause a type mismatch error because it will return List<Asteroid> while the function needs to return LiveData<List<Asteroid>>

Comment: Try that. we are actually transforming live data value. the return type will be LiveData<List<Asteroid>>

Comment: I have tried it and it's showing the type mismatch error

Comment: Sorry Mate! I was having some typo that cause the issus , it's actually returning a LiveData!